# How to rotate a Virtual Object in ARKit with Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, xcode9-beta, arkit

I am trying to make a VirtualObject, in Apple's new ARKit, rotate.  I want the object to rotate infinitely until it is stopped.  I have tried multiple things, such as:

```
angleDegrees = Int(((object.eulerAngles.y) * 180) / Float.pi) % 360
object.eulerAngles.y = initialObjectAngle + amoutnToSpinPerSpin
```

... but nothing seemed to work.  I have the virtual object setup and with a press of a button, I would like the object to spin.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that ARKit is not a rendering / display technology. The main thing ARKit does for you is set things up so that whatever graphics technology you choose — SceneKit, Unity, your own custom engine, etc — can easily render on top of the camera feed in a way that makes for good AR experiences. So any question about how to draw or animate AR content is really a question about whichever display technology you're using.

That looks like SceneKit in this case. Have you looked at the (admittedly rather sparse) [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit) for SceneKit, which includes its several ways to do animation? There's also sample code attached to the [SceneKit WWDC sessio](http://Check%20out%20SceneKit:%20What's%20New%20from%20#WWDC17%20https://developer.apple.com/wwdc17/604)n from this year (and years past) that demonstrates... well, a whole lot of things, but there are continuous spinning animations in there.

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't sure if there was different code required when using ARKit or if it was the same as a usual SceneKit.  But thank you.

Answer (score 2):

All "traditional" techniques can rotate an object in AR World. For example you may use CABasicAnimation (with repeatCount = .infinity), or you may use SCNAction (with repeatForever). Bellow is simple code to rotate the object node around axis y:

```
let action = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(2 * Double.pi), z: 0, duration: 10)
let repAction = SCNAction.repeatForever(action)
node.runAction(repAction, forKey: "myrotate")
```

To stop:

```
node.removeAction(forKey: "myrotate")
```

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple you have to just add and run a action to rotate a virtual object like this

```
    let rotateOne = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(Float.pi), z: 0, duration: 5.0)
   // let hoverUp = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 0.2, z: 0, duration: 2.5) // to hover up  with rotation
   // let hoverDown = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -0.2, z: 0, duration: 2.5) // to hover down with rotation
   // let hoverSequence = SCNAction.sequence([hoverUp, hoverDown]) // to do this in sequence first it will hover up and then hover down
   // let rotateAndHover = SCNAction.group([rotateOne, hoverSequence]) // rotation with hovering
   // let repeatForever = SCNAction.repeatForever(rotateAndHover) // to rotate the object continuously with hovering
    let repeatForever = SCNAction.repeatForever(rotateOne) // to rotate the object continuously without hovering
    node.runAction(repeatForever) // here node is your virtual object
```